# Spring Security user logged in but redirected to access denied page

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-security

I am currently working on a project with Spring 4, Spring Security 4, Hibernate 4, MySQL 5. When I login with the user credentials, it logs in but takes me to unauthenticated user page. I tried debugging the code in eclipse but I am not able to find out why it goes to the unauthenticated user page. We are using 4 different types of users for the project, so the database design given to me was a little different.

I have also asked the same question in coderanch 4 days ago but I didn't receive any answers. Here is the link to the question [Coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/666958/Spring/Spring-Security-redirects-correct-user). I have added the source files there for reference.

If you guys need any more files, please ask me and I shall provide you the same here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people looking answers to this question, here is the trick. You will have to add "ROLE_" in your SimpleGrantedAuthority object if you are fetching roles from database. That is

```
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + user.getType());
```

The explanation of why we should add the "ROLE_" token is given in this [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-minimal).

> From the docs,
>     The prefix "ROLE_" is a marker which indicates that a simple comparison with the user’s authorities should be made. In other words, a normal role-based check should be used. Access-control in Spring Security is not limited to the use of simple roles (hence the use of the prefix to differentiate between different types of security attributes).

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will help u to understand how its working, and fix ur prblm:
[Spring MVC 4 + Spring Security 4 + Hibernate Example](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-and-spring-security-4-integration-example/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually saw that example earlier but I was not able to derive the solution from that.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by Parthe, you may want to make sure the user account you used to log in have at least one of the roles listed ("SUPER ADMIN","ADMIN","STAFF").